# filter results from show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails app I have a users_controller with an action that displays a users profile, but I would like it to only display a users profile if the user has a specific value set in the database called is_rec set to true.

The below is my attempt but it doesn't work. I used a scope for the index and that worked well but I wasn't able to get a scope to work when I was working with the `show action`

```
def rec_profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  
  @user if @user.is_rec == 'true'
end
```

I could do something like this in the view but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it in the controller instead?

```
<% if @user.rec == 'true' %>
  <% show page here %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your last line in your action is irrelevant; the `@user` variable is already set--what's returned by `rec_profile` is irrelevant. If you want it to *be* relevant, instead, render a different partial if the value is not `'true'` (although I'd sure wrap that up in a method; string compares are teh gross).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find_by` and pass 1 or more attributes to look for in your database. So you could pass the id and is_rec attributes and get your user.

```
User.find_by(id: params[:id], is_rec: true)
```

Or you can use where to get all users where is_rec is true and then filter for the user whose id matches with params[:id]:

```
User.where(is_rec: true).find(params[:id])
```

Which eventually can be converted to a scope for easy access:

```
scope :with_rec, -> { where(is_rec: true) }
```

For being used then as:

```
User.with_rec.find(params[:id])
```

`with_rec` is just an example name as scope, you could use whatever you want.